# Optimize simple MySQL GROUP BY query that is stuck on "Creating sort index"

Tags: mysql, group-by, innodb, database-performance

I have a simple MySQL 5.6.23 GROUP BY query that is taking 32 seconds to run on an [RDS db.r3.xlarge instance](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/). The InnoDB table has about 47M rows. `explain` says I'm selecting about 8K of them. The final GROUP BY output has 86 rows.

According to `show processlist;` 99% of the time is spent on `Creating sort index`. If I greatly increase the number of ids in the `menu_id in (...)` list, the query takes 10-30 minutes.

Unfortunately, I cannot copy/paste text from the database server to this terminal, so tabular output below is abbreviated.

**Query info:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count_user_id, org, category
  FROM menu_views
  WHERE menu_id in (
    ...about 1300 ids...
  ) GROUP BY org, category;

explain;
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                                                           | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                 |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | SIMPLE      | menu_views | range | i_menu_view_menu_id,tyler_group,tyler_user_group,tyler_user_menu_group,tyler_menu_group | i_menu_views_menu_id | 5       | NULL | 7914 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
```

**Output:**

```
| count_user_id | org | category |
|--------------------------------|
| 13000         | foo | pizza    |
| 1             | bar | candy    |
| 90            | baz | cheese   |
| 80            | gaz | soda     |
| 150           | urk | pizza    |
|     ... etc (86 rows) ...      |
|--------------------------------|
```

**Background info:**

```
describe menu_views;

| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default |
|------------------------------------------------|
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| menu_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
| user_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
| category | varchar(255) | NO   |     | UNKNOWN |
| org      | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | UNKNOWN |
|------------------------------------------------|

show index from menu_views;

| Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| PRIMARY                | 1            | id          |
| i_menu_views_menu_id   | 1            | menu_id     |
| tyler_group            | 1            | org         |
| tyler_group            | 2            | category    |
| tyler_user_group       | 1            | user_id     |
| tyler_user_group       | 2            | org         |
| tyler_user_group       | 3            | category    |
| tyler_user_menu_group  | 1            | user_id     |
| tyler_user_menu_group  | 2            | menu_id     |
| tyler_user_menu_group  | 3            | org         |
| tyler_user_menu_group  | 4            | category    |
| tyler_menu_group       | 1            | menu_id     |
| tyler_menu_group       | 2            | org         |
| tyler_menu_group       | 3            | category    |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
```

There are other indexes on the table, but these are the ones that appear via `EXPLAIN`. I added the `tyler_*` ones to try to force a [loose index scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-optimization.html), but it's not helping.

The `org` and `category` fields properly belong on `users`, but I denormalized them in hopes that a non-JOIN query would be faster. However, I haven't seen any performance improvement.

**Full disclosure:** I am using several variants of this query, all of which are slow. This is the simplest variant. Others include a `WHERE created_at BETWEEN ('X' and 'Y')` and `GROUP BY year/month/week/day(created_at), category`.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to finally be on the right track, after staring at lots of other people's code and blog posts. I realized that I am never going to achieve a [loose index scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-optimization.html) because of my use of `COUNT` and a `GROUP BY`.

It turned out that the truly slow part is the `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`. I can run the exact same query with `COUNT(user_id)` and receive results in two seconds. Much faster, but the wrong data for my purposes.

My current optimized version, using a subquery, is:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS count_user_id, org, category FROM (
  SELECT user_id, org, category
  FROM menu_views
  WHERE menu_id IN (
     ... lots of ids ... 
  ) GROUP BY user_id, org, category
) AS groupings
GROUP BY org, category;
```

I think I still need to play with indexes and the like, but this runs in 20% of the time of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Give these a try:

```
INDEX(user_id, org, category) -- covering index for either of your queries.
INDEX(created_at, category)  -- for the additional example
```

The output implies that it had to touch over 13K rows.  With the above index, it can do all the work in the index, without having to reach over to the data.

(Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.)

With 47M rows, you should consider 'normalizing' `org` and `category` -- I assume there are a lot of repeats in those fields?  I can't tell whether our queries are I/O-bound, but this would decrease the likelihood of such.